# Let $f_n : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)= nx \int_{nx}^{nx+1}y^{-2}e^{\frac{n}{y}} \ dy$. Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)= nx \int_{nx}^{nx+1}y^{-2}e^{\frac{n}{y}} \ dy$. Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise. Is the convergence uniform?

Letting $u = \frac{n}{y}$ I have that $dy =-\frac{y^2}{n} \ du$ so the integral becomes $$f_n(x)=-x\left( e^{\frac{n}{1+nx}}-e \right) \to -x(e^\frac{1}{x}-e)$$ which would imply pointwise convergence? How can I determine if this is uniform? I'm not sure I should approach epsilon-delta since $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|-x\left( e^{\frac{n}{1+nx}}-e \right)--x(e^\frac{1}{x}-e)|$$ isn't very nice to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} \left| {f_n (x) - f(x)} \right| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} x\left| {e^{\frac{n}{{1 + nx}}}  - e^{\frac{1}{x}} } \right| \ge \frac{1}{n}\left| {e^{\frac{n}{2}}  - e^n } \right| > \frac{1}{n}\frac{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
whence the sequence cannot converge uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Each function $f_n$ is bounded on $(0,1]$, but$$\lim_{x\to0}x\left(e^{1/x}-e\right)=\infty.$$When a sequence of bounded functions converges uniformly, its limit is bounded too.